# Match two lists of matrices (row-wisely) in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

`a` and `b` are two lists in which the object number are the same. The objects containing in both `a` and `b` are matrix".

```
a<-list(matrix(c(1,2,2),1,3),matrix(c(2,1,1,1,2,2),2,3),matrix(,0,3))
b<-list(matrix(c(2,2,2),1,3),matrix(c(1,1,2),1,3),matrix(c(1,2,1),1,3))
> a
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    2

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    1    2
[2,]    1    1    2

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]

> b
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    2

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    2

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    1
```

From above, we can see there are 3 objects (i.e. matrix) in `a` and `b`. The row number in each matrix in list `a` varies, while the row number in each matrix of list `b` are the same (`nrow=1`). I want to compare each row of `a` with the corresponding row in `b`, and to calculate how many positions (in respective columns) are the same.

Let's take the second object in both `a` and `b` for an example. In `a`, object 2 is a matrix (`ncol=3, nrow=2`), we need to compare each row with the second matrix in `b`. The first row in the second object of `a` is `2  1  2`, we can see that the second and third numbers are the same with the second object in `b` (`1  1  2`), so the output is `2`, then we continually use the second row (`1  1  2`) for comparison, we find that the three number are all the same with the object `2` in list `b`, so the output is `3`.

The expected result is as follows:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 0
```

I used the following code to calculate:

```
Map(function(a,b) matrix(sapply(1:3, function(x) {a[,x]==b[,x]}),ncol=3),a,b)

[[1]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] FALSE TRUE TRUE

[[2]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] FALSE TRUE TRUE
[2,]  TRUE TRUE TRUE

[[3]]
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] Logical,0 Logical,0 Logical,0
```

But I don't know how to go on to sum the result, since there is `Logical,0` in the third object. Could you help me with this? Thank you. Or whether there are other ways to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option:

```
Map(function(x,y) apply(x, 1, function(z) rowSums(z == y)), a, b)
#[[1]]
#[1] 2
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2 3
#
#[[3]]
#numeric(0)
```

Comment: Nice solution but it only works for OP's example and does not for `a=list(structure(c(1, 2, 2), .Dim = c(1L, 3L)), structure(c(2, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2), .Dim = 2:3), structure(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 
2, 1), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))); b=list(structure(c(2, 2, 2), .Dim = c(1L, 3L)), structure(c(1, 
1, 2), .Dim = c(1L, 3L)), structure(c(1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3), .Dim = 2:3))`

Comment: @m0h3n, OP specified "the row number in each matrix of list b are the same (nrow=1)"